# How to position Widgets on exactly positions in a Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to position the `Button` a bit lower and the `Widget` with the `Text` and the `Image` a bit higher, and don't know how to do. `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` is not a solution, because this would be to high for the `Widget` and too low for the `Button`.

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (isShown == true) SkillJonglieren(),
                Flexible(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                      width: 230,
                      height: 130,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('Show Skill',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isShown = true;
```

Next thing: the `Text` and the `Image` are one `stateless Widget`. I want a bit of free space between them, but when I implement the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` for the `Column` (in which they are), It somehow doesn't work.

```
class SkillJonglieren extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Jonglieren',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
          ),
          Image.asset('images/jonglieren.jpg')
        ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use MainAxisAlignment.center and add a SizedBox of comfortable height between the two widgets.

Comment: Thanks! That SizedBox solved both problems. Actually I wanted to put a screenshot of the emulator in my question. Can you tell me, how to make one and where to find the screenshot?

Comment: There is a camera icon beside the android emulator that takes screenshots... You'll find more info on Google.

Comment: Hmm... I saw that icon but didn't knew, where to find the screenshot. I didn't found an answer on Google.

Comment: It goes to the Desktop by default.

Comment: @RohanTaneja yes, I have noticed a few hours ago. I just was very blind. But thank you for answering